# Showing images conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on a simple website for a while now. The basic coding and CSS are complete, so I am now looking to expand by adding certain features to the website. As it is a fully functioning website that serves a purpose, the main source of revenue comes from Google AdSense. I am looking for a way to show an image if Adblock is detected and another one if if it not.

The method I've found for detecting whether AdSense is active is shown below:

JS (saved as `advertisement.js`)

```
document.write('<div id="TestAdBlock" style="display:none;">an advertisement</div>');
```

The HTML bit:

```
<div id="adblockFrame">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/advertisement.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (document.getElementById("TestAdBlock") != undefined)
        {
            document.write('<strong>ADBlock Plus</strong> NOT detected!');
        }
        else
        {
            document.write('<strong>ADBlock Plus</strong> detected!');
        }
   </script>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#adblockFrame {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

What I'm asking is that if someone could be kind enough to show me how, instead of displaying text, the JS would show an image in its place. I'm not that good with JS so I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: Off-topic: [Don't use `document.write`!](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29). Use `.innerHTML` or DOM methods instead

Comment: 1. Add jQuery. 2. In javascript file write $('#TestAdBlock').html('<img src="/path/to/img.jpg" />)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an empty target div :

```
<div id="adblockDetector"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        if (document.getElementById("TestAdBlock") != undefined)
        {
            document.getElementById('adblockDetector').innerHTML="<img src='noadblock.jpg' alt='no adblock' />";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('adblockDetector').innerHTML="<img src='adblock.jpg' alt='Adblock detected!' />";
        }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jquery, just because you tagged it:

html

```
<div id="wheretoappend"></div>
```

js

```
var whereToAppend = '#wheretoappend';
 var myDiv = $('<div/>', {id: 'mydiv'});
 ($('#adblockFrame').length)
 ? myDiv.addClass('hasit').appendTo(whereToAppend)
 : myDiv.addClass('doesnt').appendTo(whereToAppend);
```

CSS

```
.hasit  {background: url('hasit.png');}
.doesnt {background: url('doesnt.png');}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, [don't use the devil `document.write`!](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document.write%28%29)

- If you want to add content to your page, use DOM methods or `.innerHTML`.
- If you want to detect AdBlock, just create a global variable in `advertisement.js`

For example:

**advertisement.js**:

```
window.TestAdBlock = true;
```

**Your page**:

```
<div id="adblockFrame">
    <img id="TestAdBlock" alt="AdBlock Detected???" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/advertisement.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var AdBlockImg = document.getElementById('TestAdBlock');
        if (window.TestAdBlock)
        {
            AdBlockImg.src = "/images/AdBlockDetected.jpg";
            AdBlockImg.alt = "AdBlock Detected!";
        }
        else
        {
            AdBlockImg.src = "/images/AdBlockNOTDetected.jpg";
            AdBlockImg.alt = "AdBlock NOT Detected!";
        }
        AdBlockImg.title = AdBlockImg.alt;
    });
   </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't use `document.write` for anything. It's just bad practice. But here's generally how I'd do it with jquery, since you tagged it:

```
<div id="adblockFrame>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/advertisement.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var adsAllowed = adsAllowed || false;
    var src = adsAllowed ? '/images/myAd.png' : '/images/noAd.png';

    $('#ad').attr('src',src);
</script>
<img id="ad"/>
</div>
```

advertisement.js

`var adsAllowed = true;`